# ffmpeg reencoding of flv files from MAC

Tags: ffmpeg, webcam, flv, re-encoding

I've recorded a video from a webcam on mac and now i'm trying to reencode it, but ffmpeg does not recognize audio stream:

```
FFmpeg version git-120610e, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Sep 21 2010 15:56:57 with gcc 4.4.1
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264
  libavutil     50.27. 0 / 50.27. 0
  libavcore      0. 9. 0 /  0. 9. 0
  libavcodec    52.89. 0 / 52.89. 0
  libavformat   52.78. 5 / 52.78. 5
  libavdevice   52. 2. 2 / 52. 2. 2
  libavfilter    1.39. 0 /  1.39. 0
  libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0
  libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
[flv @ 0x1e79470] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, flv, from '10125174c09241f6536ccbe503ebbc00.flv':
  Duration: 00:00:22.68, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0.0: Video: flv, yuv420p, 640x480, 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: [0][0][0][0] / 0x0000, 0 channels
```

Is it possible to make ffmpeg to support audio stream form flv recorded on MAC?

Answer (score 0):

Use [GSpot](http://www.headbands.com/gspot/) to determine what the Audio Codec in the stream truly is.  I've never seen FFMPEG throw such an odd format back like that.  Once you know the codec you may need to recompile FFMPEG with some additional libraries and dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I bet there's no audio stream really in the video...  you can add the parameter `-an` to exclude the audio track altogether and it should encode just the video stream, or you can add a different input as the audio.